# Why does (~(1 << 31)) === ~(1 << 31) yet they aren't equal when converted to strings?

Tags: javascript, binary, tostring, bitwise-operators

In JS:

```
(~(1 << 31)) === ~(1 << 31)
> true
(~(1 << 31)).toString(2) === ~(1 << 31).toString(2)
> false
```

How is this possible? I thought the `===` operator was a strict comparison between identical entities?

Comment: One is `"1111111111111111111111111111111"`, the other is `-1`, so they are clearly not the same

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/hn24rc97/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the expression is evaluated like:

```
(~(1 << 31)).toString(2) === ~((1 << 31).toString(2))
//----------------------------^ see the parenthesis
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I wasn't comparing exact values due to Order of Operations in JS:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

The member access `.toString()` takes precedence over the bitwise operator. Whoops!